# Do I need to add a resistor before a relay?

Tags: gpio, safety

I want my Raspberry Pi B+ to periodically check if my Raspberry Pi 3 is still running (not frozen). If it is frozen, I wan't my B+ to hard reset my Pi3 by pulling the power, then giving it power again after a few seconds.

I have bought a 3.3V relay of ebay (view it [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/3.3V_Relay/182496548793)) and plan to use it as a switch for the power line of a USB cable.

I have tested the relay directly connected to GPIO pin 18, and GPIO ground. The relay works correctly like this.

My question is: **Should I (or do I need) to use a current limiting resistor?** Is there any chance of bad stuff happening if I continue to directly connect it to GPIO 18 and ground?

Answer (score 1):

What you linked is a relay driver, not a relay. It appears to have current limiting on the opto-coupler, although you would never know from the sketchy "data".

If you want to reboot if the Pi is not running you do not **need** any external hardware, you can use the inbuilt watchdog timer.

[Here's a link to more information on the Raspberry Pi's built in Watchdog timer](http://www.switchdoc.com/2014/11/reliable-projects-using-internal-watchdog-timer-raspberry-pi/).

[Here's another link on how to use the Pi's Watchdog timer](http://blog.ricardoarturocabral.com/2013/01/auto-reboot-hung-raspberry-pi-using-on.html).

Here's a schematic of the "relay driver" you referenced.  It shows that the driver can control a solenoid which would actually control the turning on/off of the power to the end device.

[image]

Comment: This may be a really stupid question, but what is the difference between a relay and a relay driver? Googling "relay driver definition" starts talking about relays (not relay drivers). Thanks for the tip about a watchdog timer, I'll look into that :)

Comment: A relay is an electro-mechanical device. Relays can switch quite high currents. A driver is a device to interface between the limited logic output of a computer to the higher current required to switch a relay. The device you bought has very limited data, so it is difficult to say what its capabilities are.